# Allowing users to choose a layer - trouble with code

Tags: google-fusion-tables

I'm having a difficult time getting the toggle to work with my layers.  I know this question has been asked before and I've read the responses.  I tried to use Kathryn's toggle_layer.html code, but I can't get it to work.

When I add the "function changeMap" code (in bold below) and IF statement code, it delete my map.

Here's my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  <style>
    #map-canvas { width:500px; height:400px; }
    .layer-wizard-search-label { font-family: sans-serif };
  </style>
  <script type="text/javascript"
    src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false">
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var map;
    var layer_0;
    var layer_1;
    function initialize() {
      map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(-23.002644973802262, 135.7124635),
        zoom: 4,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
      });
      layer_0 = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
        query: {
          select: "col2>>1",
          from: "1HpTDVhKXNMEs59ins5DfwbaEOpRevJ79yEuKSYw"
        },
        map: map,
        styleId: 2,
        templateId: 2
      });
      layer_1 = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
        query: {
          select: "col2>>1",
          from: "1HpTDVhKXNMEs59ins5DfwbaEOpRevJ79yEuKSYw"
        },
        map: map,
        styleId: 3,
        templateId: 4
      });
    }
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

function changeMap(layerNum) {
  if (layerNum == 2) {
    update(layer_0);
  }
  if (layerNum == 3) {
    update(layer_1);
  }
}

function update(layer) {
  var layerMap = layer.getMap();
  if (layerMap) {
    layer.setMap(null);
  } else {
    layer.setMap(map);
  }
}

</script>


</head>
<body onload="initialize();">

<input type="checkbox" value="2" onclick="changeMap(this.value)" checked="checked" />Layer 1
<input type="checkbox" value="3" onclick="changeMap(this.value)" checked="checked" />Layer 2
<div id="map_canvas"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your css and html are not consistent. If I change:

```
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```

To:

```
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
```

The map appears and the toggles work. [working example](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_SO_FusionTables_toggle20130715.html)

(alternatively, you could fix the css or put the css inline)

Comment: BTW, you have some great maps examples on your site!

Comment: Do you know how I could change this to a dropdown menu, so that it only shows one lay at a time, and defaults to the standard map (or a layer I choose)?

Comment: You mean change the checkboxes to HTML select options?

Comment: I think select options in a dropdown like this: https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/samples/change_query   And radio button like you have here:  http://www.geocodezip.com/fish_freeshell_org_vegmap_indexAPIa.html